# SLURM array of jobs, each executing on a different node

Tags: cluster-computing, slurm

I would like to have `hostname` run once on four different nodes. This is what I'm trying:

```
balter@exahead1:~/slurm_tutorial$ cat nodes.sub
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --job-name=nodes
#SBATCH --array=0-3
#SBATCH --nodes=4
#SBATCH --tasks-per-node=1
##SBATCH --ntasks=4
#SBATCH --output="nodes_%N_%A_%a_%j.out"
#SBATCH --error="nodes_%N_%A_%a_%j.err"

srun hostname


balter@exahead1:~/slurm_tutorial$ sbatch nodes.sub
Submitted batch job 516
balter@exahead1:~/slurm_tutorial$ for i in *.out; do echo "*** $i ***"; cat $i; done
*** nodes_exanode-2-8_516_0_517.out ***
exanode-2-8
exanode-4-44
exanode-4-12
exanode-6-0
*** nodes_exanode-2-8_516_1_518.out ***
exanode-2-8
exanode-4-12
exanode-4-44
exanode-6-0
*** nodes_exanode-2-8_516_2_519.out ***
exanode-2-8
exanode-4-44
exanode-4-12
exanode-6-0
*** nodes_exanode-2-8_516_3_516.out ***
exanode-2-8
exanode-4-44
exanode-4-12
exanode-6-0
```